# CSS syntax to set all the font color of all divs inside the tds of table "registration" red?

Tags: css

What is the correct CSS syntax to set the font color of all divs inside the tds of table "registration" red?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS:

```
table.registration div {
    color: red !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="registration">
<tr>
    <td><div>This text will be red</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Since the OP explicitly mentioned the `div`s inside `td`s, perhaps consider adding `td` between `.registration` and `div` in your CSS.

Comment: basically makes that particularly setting "sticky", so that it can't be overridden by a later style setting, unless that later setting is itself marked !important.

Comment: rockerest: the only place a div would be allowed within a table is inside a td or td, so adding td/th to the css would be superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

```
#registration td div { color:red; }
```

or

```
table.registration td div { color:red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#registration td div { color:red }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.registration td div {color:red /* #ff0000 */}
```